# How to sort associative array by its value using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an associative array like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Admin
            [email] => admin@admin.com
            [group] => Admin
            [href] => http://localhost/teradasys/index.php/users/user/user_info?&user_id=1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => rochellecanale
            [email] => rochellecanale11@gmail.com
            [group] => 
            [href] => http://localhost/teradasys/index.php/users/user/user_info?&user_id=2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => symfony
            [email] => chelle@flax.ph
            [group] => 
            [href] => http://localhost/teradasys/index.php/users/user/user_info?&user_id=3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => jolopeterson
            [email] => jolo@flax.ph
            [group] => 
            [href] => http://localhost/teradasys/index.php/users/user/user_info?&user_id=4
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [name] => symfony123
            [email] => symfony123@gmail.com
            [group] => 
            [href] => http://localhost/teradasys/index.php/users/user/user_info?&user_id=5
        )
```

I want to sort by `name` how can I do it?

Comment: [**This might be the answer your looking for.**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2699159/4672534)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[uasort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) function is what you're looking for.

```
uasort($data, function($a, $b) { return strcasecmp($a['name'], $b['name']); });
```

You should take a look on **usort()** and **uksort()** doc for examples of how user-defined comparison functions works.

Comment: Thank you a lot, been looking for this for a long time!

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

This is my go to page for sorting. If you want to have array keys preserved you would do something like:

```
uasort($myArray, function ($a, $b) {
    if ($a['name'] == $b['name']) return 0;
    return ($a['name'] < $b['name']) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Switch the comparison to change or ordering. If you are using this sort often you might want to extract it to its own function rather than use a closure. Personally, a sort closure is pretty short and I like to have it inline where I can see exactly what is going on without needing to jump to another bit of code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$nameA = array();
foreach ($inventory as $key => $row)
{
    $nameA[$key] = $row['name'];
}
array_multisort($nameA, SORT_ASC, $inventory);
```

Here

> $inventory

is your main array

Comment: Ok thanks. I didn't yet check the link you posted above. Ill try this.